# Fine-grained authorisation with ZODB

Tags: python, zodb

I have been looking into using ZODB as a persistence layer for a multiplayer video game. I quite like how seamlessly it integrates with arbitrary object-oriented data structures. However, I am stumbling over one issue, where I can't figure out, whether ZODB can resolve this for me.

Apparently, one can use the `ClientStorage` from ZEO to access a remote data storage used for persistence. While this is great in a trusted local network, one can't do this without proper authorization and authentication in an open network.

So I was wondering, if there is any chance to realize the following concept with ZODB:

On the server-side I would like to have a ZEO server running plus a simulation of the game world that might operate as a fully authorized client on the ZEO server (or use the same file storage as the ZEO server).

On the client side I'd need very restricted read/write access to the ZEO server, so that a client can only view the information its user is supposed to know about (e.g. the surrounding area of their character) and can only modify information related to the actions that their character can perform.

These restrictions would have to be imposed by the server using some sort of fine-grained authorisation scheme. So I would need to be able to tell the server whether user A has permissions to read/write object B.

Now is there way to do this in ZODB or third-party solutions for this kind of problem? Or is there a way to extend ZEO in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ZEO was never designed for such use.

It is designed for scaling ZODB access across multiple processes instead, with authentication and authorisation left to the application on top of the data.

I would not use ZEO for anything beyond a local network anyway. Use a different protocol to handle communication between game clients and game server instead, keeping the ZODB server side only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ;) I meanwhile realized that ZODB uses pickle internally, which should generally not be used in for online client-server communication.

Comment: Yup, that is a huge aspect making any direct ZODB access on untrusted clients a no-go area.